# List over assigned global Ethernet MAC multicast address

Tags: ethernet, mac-address, multicast

Where are global Ethernet multicast MAC addresses assigned?  Is this by Organizationally Unique Identifier (OUI), and if so, is there a homepage that shows all the assigned global Ethernet MAC multicast address?

Examples of currently assigned multicast MAC addresses are:

- 01-00-5E-??-??-?? : [IPv4 Multicast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast#Layer_2_delivery)
- 01-80-C2-00-00-0? : [Spanning Tree Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree_protocol)

Comment: There is a correlation between Multicast IP address and MAC address, check out ['Mapping of IP Multicast Addresses to Ethernet/FDDI addresses'](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Multicast-HOWTO-2.html#ss2.4) for for a quick tutorial.  Let us know if you need any further clarification or if that doesn't answer any of your question.

Comment: The mapping of IP multcast to Ethernet addresses covers one example of assigned MAC multicast addresses.  A assume that there is a list of all assigned addresses somewhere, so new multicast addresses can be provided with collision.

Comment: He's asking who assigns the MACs for various protocol use.  The two examples given are the *source MAC* for the protocol, not the multicast *destination MAC*.  IEEE controls OUIs.

Comment: @RickyBeam: The listed MAC addresses are used as **destination** addresses, according to the protocol description in the Wikipedia links.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: 01 marks it as multicast (or broadcast) 01-00-5e is an OUI belonging to IANA, 01-80-c2 belongs to IEEE 802.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

01-00-5E-??-??-?? : [IANA Ethernet Numbers](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ethernet-numbers/ethernet-numbers.xhtml#ethernet-numbers-3)
01-80-C2-00-00-0? : [IEEE Standards Group Listings](http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/grpmac/public.html)

That covers the two OUI's you listed.

> Is there a homepage which shows all assigned global Ethernet MAC multicast address?

There is no *single* source, because each organization controls the use of their OUI. (IANA and IEEE in the above examples.) Any mac address is converted to multicast by [changing a single bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address#Ethernet)

Comment: You forgot IPv6 multicast address mapping: 33-33-XX-XX-XX-XX (see your first link)

Answer (score 2):

Wireshark provides [a list](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf) but I think you have to filter out the multicast addresses by yourself.

Comment: Wireshark's list is built from many sources, including "no authority" unregistered usage.

Comment: Thanks, both addresses are there, but how is this Wireshark list build... there must be some authoritative list somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

The IEEE controlled list of assigned addresses at [MA-L PUBLIC LISTING](http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/public.html) shows the assigned addresses as blocks in unicast address format, thus with cleared LSB of first byte, e.g. 0x00.  Any vendor with a vendor block, can use that to create a unique multicast address block, simply by setting the LSB of first byte, e.g. 0x01.

For the examples:

- 01-00-5E-??-??-?? : Based on the 00-00-5E vendor block given to "ICANN, IANA Department"
- 01-80-C2-00-00-0? : Based on the 00-80-C2 vendor block given to "IEEE 802.1 COMMITTEE"

Answer (score -1):

I will explain this in simple word
As you know there are L2 & L3 protocols, for the L2 protocols we don't have IP address relate to Multicast Frame exchange between group members and thus we must select Multicast MAC address (IEEE). Now for the the L3 protocols there is IP address relate to Multicast Packet and thus by using this and MAC address "01-00-5E" we can create Multicast MAC-address for Frame exchange between group members.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.